# How to install varnish cache on AWS elastic beanstalk?

Tags: linux, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, yum

I am trying to install varnish cache on AWS elastic beanstalk.I have used

```
yum install varnish
```

Its asks some input like

```
Is this ok [y/d/N]:
```

I want to hit "Y" by command. Is there any other way ?

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use the `-y` option to `yum`, like this:

```
yum -y install varnish
```

This will automatically answer yes on any questions during the install.

Comment: Sorry, I feel I need to down vote this answer. I'd beware of running `yum` from the command prompt on Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances, as the effects won't stick. Use `.ebextensions` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, don't use `yum` directly on Elastic Beanstalk for anything but research and debugging, as the changes won't stick if Elastic Beanstalk decides to scale or rebuild the environment.

If you need a specific package on your instance, you probably want to install it through [.ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-packages) and the `packages:` directive, like so:

```
packages:
    yum:
        varnish: []
```

Good luck!

Comment: yes i tried like this (   01-command: 
    command: yum install php-pear php-devel httpd-devel pcre-devel gcc make
    ignoreErrors: true
 ) in .ebextensions